# question about dedekid cut, multiplicative inverse

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Walter Rudin's 『Principles of Mathematical Analysis』says that *cut* is a subset $\alpha$ of $Q$(set of rational numbers) which satisfies following axioms.

1. $\alpha \ne \emptyset$ and $\alpha \ne Q$.
2. If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \in Q$ and $q \lt p$, then $q \in \alpha$.
3. If $p \in \alpha$, then there is $r \in \alpha$ such that $p \lt r$.

The book shows that the set of cuts $R$ forms an ordered set under $\alpha \lt \beta \iff \alpha \subsetneq \beta$ and satisfies field axioms about addition under the definition $\alpha + \beta = \lbrace r + s \mid \exists r \in \alpha \exists s \in \beta (r \in \alpha \land s \in \beta) \rbrace$. And the book defines a multiplication of two **positive**(a cut which contains positive rational numbers) cuts $\alpha, \beta$ by $\alpha \beta = \lbrace p \mid \exists r \in \alpha \exists s \in \beta (p \lt rs \land r \gt 0 \land s \gt 0) \rbrace$.

But the book doesn't shows that $R^+$(set of positive cuts) satisfies field axioms about multiplication under this definition. I proved field axioms but one; every elements of $R^+$ has a multiplicative inverse.

I defined multiplicative inverse of a cut $\alpha$ by $\alpha^{-1} = \lbrace p \mid p \le 0 \lor [p \gt 0 \land \exists q \gt 0 (\frac{1}{p} - q \notin \alpha)] \rbrace$ and proved that $\alpha^{-1}$ is a positive cut and $\alpha \alpha^{-1} \subset 1^*$($1^*$ is multiplicative identity of cuts. set of rational numbers smaller than $1$). But i could not prove that $1^* \subset \alpha \alpha^{-1}$.

**My question is here.**

How can it be proved that $p \in 1^*$ implies $p \in \alpha \alpha^{-1}$? If it can't, is my definition wrong?